# ¿Límites en número aleatorio Python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo poner límites a cada número aleatorio obtenido, que cada número no sea mayor que 4:

**Ejemplo:** (4, 3, 4, 4, 4) sum = 19

**Ejemplo2:** (2, 2, 4, 4, 4) sum = 16

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from random import sample
from itertools import izip

def slice_lengths(length=19, cuts=4):
    """Take a theoretical ribbon and slice it cuts number of times.

    The return value is a generator of the different lengths made.
    Parameters:
        length, a number greater than zero
        cuts, a number less than length
    """

    # Calculate where the positions of the ribbon edges will be.
    edge = [0] + sorted(sample(xrange(1, length), cuts)) + [length]

    # Deltas for a moving window of two values across edge.
    return ((b - a) for a, b in izip(edge, edge[1:]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = tuple(slice_lengths())
    print s, "sum =", sum(s)
```

Comment: Luis, me parece por tus comentarios que tu pregunta no está del todo clara: ¿Estás buscando generar números aleatorios no mayores a `cuts` y que a su vez el conjunto sume `length`?

Comment: SI, no mayores a cuts y que de como resultado length pero que cada numero aleatorio obtenido no supere el numero 4 osea si yo pongo en length=14 como resultado entregue: (4, 2, 3, 3, 2) sum = 14

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar la función `mod` a la salida de `slice_lengths`

```
from random import sample
from itertools import izip
from operator import mod

def slice_lengths(length=19, cuts=4):
    """Take a theoretical ribbon and slice it cuts number of times.

    The return value is a generator of the different lengths made.
    Parameters:
        length, a number greater than zero
        cuts, a number less than length
    """

    # Calculate where the positions of the ribbon edges will be.
    edge = [0] + sorted(sample(xrange(1, length), cuts)) + [length]

    # Deltas for a moving window of two values across edge.
    return (1 + mod((b - a),5) for a, b in izip(edge, edge[1:]))



s = tuple(slice_lengths())
print s, "sum =", sum(s)
```

Ahí estoy devolviendo números del 1 al 4. Si quieres del 0 al 4 quita el `1 +` del return

[Fiddle de ejemplo](https://repl.it/@ffflabs/WeeUpsetCrustacean)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda pero el length=19 siempre tiene que dar como suma length eso se podria hacer?

Comment: O sea quieres obtener una combinación de 5 números, del 1 al 4, que entre sí sumen 19?

Comment: si eso realmente me seria de mucha ayuda